# IfcConvert --center-model-geometry: how calculate new center coordinates?

Tags: python, ifc, ifc-open-shell

I tried to use IfcConvert on a IFC georeferenced model, with --center-model-geometry parameter.
As outup a collada (.dae) file is generated and the model is translated by unknown values (x, y, z).
In order to place in correct position the model, i need to know the coordinates of the new calculated center.

In which way i can obtain the geographic coordinates of the new center?